# Passing in Array data into div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So I need to get an array of values rendering in a selection of divs, could anyone help me as to the best way to tackle this?

I have to use javaScript.

Comment: What did you already tried? Do you have example data of which values in what kind of divs?

Comment: Can you use jQuery or it's just with JavaScript ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for being brief. Yeah ideally if it could be in jQuery that would be the best option.

Comment: @BasvanDijk So it will just be a standard array and they just have to be popped in a div element.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt  
Hi, sorry for being brief. Yeah ideally if it could be in jQuery that would be the best option.

Comment: @nattie87 See if my solution is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can add DOM elements with JavaScript by creating the element you want, setting the properties/attributes as you desire, and then appending them to the DOM (either directly to the body, or to a containing element), like so:

```js
var arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
var container = document.getElementById("container");
arr.forEach(function (text) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = text;
  div.classList.add("div-added");
  container.append(div);
});
```

```css
.div-added {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can use jQuery, like so:

```js
var arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
var container = $("#container");
arr.forEach(function(text) {
  var div = $("<div>", {
    text: text,
    class: "div-added"
  });
  container.append(div);
});
```

```css
.div-added {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: So helpful @mhodges